# Advice in Objective-C OOP Design

Tags: objective-c, oop

I have a class A with methods `update` & `updatedMessage:(BOOL) isMatched points:(int) points`.

Now I was thinking of creating at least 3 subclass, with different implementation on a particular method. However inside this implemented method on the subclass I still need to call
instance methods implemented from the superclass and update an instance variable. So I am calling these methods using:

```
[super updateMessage];
[super.flippedCards addObject:newObj];
```

Is there a better approach? Is this approach okay? Any disadvantage?

Thank you.

Comment: Only call `[super xxx]` from an overridden implementation of the `xxx` method.

Answer (score 0):

Unless those methods are overridden in your child class and you specifically want to call the super class's implementation of those methods, you can just call them on yourself:

```
[self updateMessage];
[self.flippedCards addObject:newObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create sub class to have different implementation on method, I think you can create a protocol with that method

```
@protocol DoSomethingProtocol
- NSString* Update:(NSString *message);
```

Create 3 class that conform this protocol and implement the method that you want it differently in these class

```
@interface  WorkerA<DoSomethingProtocol>
@interface  WorkerB<DoSomethingProtocol>
@interface  WorkerC<DoSomethingProtocol>
```

And in your class A, declare

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<DoSomethingProtocol> worker;
```

If you want this class do something like WorkerA could do, just assign it with a Worker A or B

```
    - (id)initWithStrategy:(id<DoSomethingProtocol>) strategy{
    // super init
    worker = strategy;
    }
```

and in your class A

```
self.message = [worker Update:self.message];
[self.flippedCards addObject:newObj];
```

so you can easy choose what the worker should do and can update instance variable in your class without calling it in children class.

This is delegate pattern in Objective-C and similar with Strategy Pattern in .NET

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I hope you guys can confirm if its okay to continue on my approach above even without using protocols.

Also, what if the superclass mentioned above is a viewcontroller that 
have outlets. I am thinking that it'll be much easier to just implement different outlets on the sub-class.

Thanks again

Comment: If your app works then its OK, but i think that it will be hard to change, fix or extend your app.

Comment: what do you use the sub-classes for ?
If you want those sub-classes (viewcontrolelr) have different layouts, different behavior and use them, i think that you will not need the super-class.
Otherwise, using delegate pattern will be easier to implement with neat code

Comment: Thanks. I have completely forgotten this issue.